# How can i use capitalize code in php on my form?

Tags: php, css, capitalize

```
$register->textInput('first_name',Lang::string('settings-first-name'),true);
```

I wanna use uppercase or capitalize in my form for this label can you help me about this?

Comment: use `strtoupper`

Comment: Ty for ur comment but the first letter entered in the form must be big as capitalize of css

Comment: Then use CSS for this issue

Comment: You can use ucfirst  [link](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: just visually or sending capital letters in request too ?

Comment: $register->textInput('first_name',Lang::string('settings-first-name'),true);

in this label it has to be visually on my form first latter capital

Comment: if I use text-transform: capitalize; in css, its working for all forms I just want to use this for one label